# TextView is not updating

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I am trying to generate random number. And to do so ,
I am getting the text from edit text and passing it to the nextInt of Random class. But i have a problem. My textView is not changing. 
Here its the code:

```
    package random.vivek.com.random;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Shiva on 09-08-2015.
 */
public class Random extends AppCompatActivity  {

    int number , i ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        java.util.Random genertor = new java.util.Random();
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.random);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);


        String s = editText.getText().toString();
        try {
            i = Integer.parseInt(s);
            for (int roll = 0; roll < 20; roll++) {
                number = genertor.nextInt(i);
            }


        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

    }






        textView.setText(number + "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put all your code in the `onCreate` method, which is wrong. The `onCreate` method is called when the activity starts. You should add a button or something to your app so that when the user presses the button, a random number gets generated. I think you have the ability to do that so I won't show you here.

In the on click listener of the button, write your code above:

public void buttonOnClick (View view) {
    java.util.Random genertor = new java.util.Random();
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.random);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

```
String s = editText.getText().toString();
try {
    i = Integer.parseInt(s);
    for (int roll = 0; roll < 20; roll++) {
       number = genertor.nextInt(i);
    }
    textView.setText (Integer.toString(number));

} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();

}
```

Comment: Yeah I just realised it and edited my post. That was stupid. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
try {
            i = Integer.parseInt(s);
            for (int roll = 0; roll < 20; roll++) {
                number = genertor.nextInt(i);
                textView.setText(number);
            }


        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: How would that work? each time the loop is called when setting the text :)

Comment: What u want to do ? Tell me ur purpose.

Answer (score 2):

## onCreate method:

First things first, you are writing this in the [onCreate](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) method. onCreate is the method where most of your initialization stuff goes.

So when the view is created there is nothing in the edittext, so you get nothing in the text view. Instead you should be doing it on the click of some button or on text change in edit text to make it more dynamic.

## Responding to edit text change:

To perform some action on edittext text change use the text watcher as follows:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String s = editText.getText().toString();
        try {
            i = Integer.parseInt(s);
            for (int roll = 0; roll < 20; roll++) {
              number = genertor.nextInt(i);
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    String s = editText.getText().toString();
    try {
        i = Integer.parseInt(s);
        for (int roll = 0; roll < 20; roll++) {
            number = genertor.nextInt(i);
            textView.setText(String.ValueOf()number);
            // But this will also keep continuing through the loop and change the text quickly.
        }
```

If you want to append the values:

```
String s = editText.getText().toString();
    try {
        i = Integer.parseInt(s);
        for (int roll = 0; roll < 20; roll++) {
            number = genertor.nextInt(i);
            textView.append(String.ValueOf()number + " ");
```

Also as it stands, your textView.setText(number + ""); the +"" does nothing.

You need to change your algorithm if you want a time delay between changing the Text of your textView.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set your textview by using textView.setText(Integer.toString(number)) in your code